# Copying an SQL table from one Server to another on SQL Server 2000 / 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I’m trying to copy a SQL Server table, schema and data, from Server A to Server B. The SQL Server table is just a reference table which hasn't been populated for some reason on Server B. Can anyone advise how the entire table could be copied across please? On SQL Server 2000/2005.

So far we've tried a long-winded approach by copying the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files from Server A to Server B with a plan to then copy the table across into the Server B database but we are having some difficulty re-attaching the database to Server B.

Please can anyone help?

Kind Regards
James

Comment: Copying and reattaching the mdb and ldf files is not a good approach. You should instead create a backup and then restore on the other server. However, this is for the ENTIRE database and it sounds like you want only a single table? For this I would use the import/export data functionality in SSMS.

Comment: When you say reference data, are we talking about a lot of reference data?  You should backup the data you want and then restore from the backup set.  Alternatively you could just export the CREATE statement from Server A and then enter the data into the table on Server B.

Comment: Have you tried the import/export options in SSMS? Right click on the source database in the object viewer to find.

Comment: Import/export data is great. Another option, create new database, SELECT * INTO NewDB.dbo.TableA FROM OldDB.dbo.TableA, then backup and restore new database with only new table in it.

Answer (score 2):

Using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):

In Object Explorer right click on source database name, Tasks.. -> Generate Scripts.. - opens Generate and Publish Scripts dialog. Click Next to choose objects, choose "Select specific DB objects", expand Tables, choose your table. Next, setup script destination, for example New query window and (important step!!) - click Advanced, and set "Types of data to script"="Schema and data" and "Script USE DATABASE"=False, OK, Next, Next, .. wait .. Finish. Now you have got complete SQL script to reproduce this table with data. Connect to destination DB and run it.

Tested with SSMS 2014, but as I recall this feature should be available starting from SSMS 2005.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the import/export data wizard in management studio, the wizard will create for you a new table in the server B with the same structure of the table in the server A. before using it you need to have at least one database in sever B.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer. And it has been mentioned in the comment 2 or 3 times already.

Comment: Hi
I've now found a YouTube clip which says you shouldn't use export and import for SQL database to SQL database.
[url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUDQT4zdXE0][/url]

It says use the Copy Database option with SSMS Tasks at 3 mins 3 seconds into the clip.

Will export and import as work just the same?

Interestingly on my home version of SQL Express, the Copy Database option does not exist - hopefully it will exist when I go into work tomorrow to give it a try :)

Kind Regards
James

Answer (score 0):

This confirms why this is one of favourite forums.

Both these methods work beautifully :

- Generate Scripts (when altering Types of data to script"="Schema and
  data")
- Export and Import

Interestingly Generate Scripts works with SQL Express perfectly but the Export method does not save unless you have at least SQL Server Standard Edition.

Thanks so much everyone
Cheers
James

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> SELECT * INTO destination FROM source

But, it will not copy the indexes and key information or you can also try import/export data task from SSMS.